Big Query export not able to exclude Events
I have configured a BQ export to get app_remove event and exclude all.
But the firebase_campaign event is not getting filtered to be excluded. I have even excluded the same by specifying the event by name.
Also, the BQ exports I have set up show the total estimated daily event volume to be exported as 0.01 / 1 million daily limit. However, I still get a limit exceeded warning, which is again due to firebase_campaign not getting filtered.
excluded the firebase_campaign event by specifying the event by name

Can you include some code or screenshots of the configuration how you've done it now?
